# Struggling with While loop

Tags: python

I am writing a while loop in python that continues to ask the user for input until they type the word quit. Whenever I run the code and type the word "quit" it continues to run.

This is the code I got so far:

```
x = input("Enter a word or type quit to exit:")
while x:
    input("Enter a word or type quit to exit:")
if x == Quit.lower():
    print("Thanks for playing!")
```

Any suggestions would be very appreciated!

Comment: Your `if` block is outside of your `for` loop.  Also, you never define the variable `Quit`.

Answer (score 0):

You're if statement is outside the while loop, so the 'if' function will only be checked after the while-loop. You should also add "-sings around "quit".

So

```
x = input("Enter a word or type quit to exit:")
while x:
    input("Enter a word or type quit to exit:")
    if x == "Quit".lower():
        print("Thanks for playing!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Some problems:

1. When taking input you have to assign it to a variable:

`a = input("Enter a word")

2. The `if` statement has to be in the while loop, not outside it.
3. There is no need for `Quit.lower()` First of all it wouldn't work, second you can just check if it is `=` "quit".
4. `While x` will not work.

So your final code is:

```
x = input("Enter a word or type quit to exit:") #Takes input
while x != "quit": # Checks if it is "quit".
    # Do something...
    x = input("Enter a word or type quit to exit:")# Takes input again.
print("Thanks for playing!")
```